# Proof of why $S^\infty$ is contractible using Hilbert space

Tags: algebraic-topology, hilbert-spaces, homotopy-theory

In John Baez's blog post http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week151.html, Baez gives a short proof of why $S^\infty$ is contractible, using that $S^\infty$ is the unit sphere in a infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

> I can't resist explaining why the unit sphere in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is contractible. It seems very odd that a sphere could be contractible, but this is one of those funny things about infinite dimensions. Take our Hilbert space to be $L^2[0,1]$ and consider any function f in the unit sphere of this Hilbert space: $$\int|f(x)|^2 dx = 1$$
>   For $t$ between $0$ and $1$, let $f_t(x)$ be a function that equals $1$ for $x < t$, and a sped-up version of $f$ for $x$ greater than or equal to $t$. If you do this right $f_t$ will still lie in the unit sphere, and you'll have a way of contracting the whole unit sphere down to a single point, namely the constant function $1$.
>   Cute, huh?

This appears to draw a path from each point in $S^\infty$ to $1$. I guess you can form the homotopy that drags each vector along its path to $1$ but I'm not sure how to show this is a contraction. I imagine doing a similar thing for $S^2$, which carries each point along a geodesic to the south pole, but the resulting homotopy would rip apart the sphere at the north pole. Obviously it shouldn't work in $S^2$, but I don't see how this is addressed in infinite dimensions. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Q: How does this proof give a contraction of $S^\infty$?

Comment: I think it should be straightforward to show that this homotopy is continuous. I see an $\epsilon/3$ proof using the triangle inequality in my head but I am not in a position to write it down to make sure it works.

Comment: Just to clarify something for people who are familiar with Hatcher: this $S^\infty$ is different from the CW complex that comes from the inverse limit of finite-dimensional spheres.  The two $S^\infty$'s are homotopy equivalent, though: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972856/in-what-sense-is-s-infty-the-same-as-x-in-ell-2-x-1  (The difference is whether vectors contain finitely or infinitely many non-zero entries.)

Comment: @KyleMiller : you probably meant "direct limit"

Comment: @Max I certainly did, thanks.